# Why is the session array showing instead of the ID?

Tags: php, session, codeigniter-3

I have several websites using codeigniter version 3.1.10 and I'm having an issue with two of them regarding sessions. They are all using database as the storage method with the only thing changing between them being the username and password being used for database access. They are using the same host with PHP version 7.2 and they all use SSL. Non-working websites are showing the session array data in the "value" field in the browser debug tool, whereas the working websites are showing just the session ID.

I have tried forcing HttpOnly via htaccess file, as that is one of the things I noticed that is different between websites. I have rebuilt my ci_sessions table using the instructions from the 3.1.10 manual. I was able to dump only the session ID using PHP.

My config file:

```
   $config['sess_cookie_name'] = 'ci_session';
   $config['sess_expiration'] = 7200;
   $config['sess_save_path'] = 'ci_sessions';
   $config['sess_match_ip'] = FALSE;
   $config['sess_time_to_update'] = 300;
   $config['sess_regenerate_destroy'] = FALSE;

   $config['cookie_prefix']    = '';
   $config['cookie_domain']    = '.domain.com';
   $config['cookie_path']        = '/';
   $config['cookie_secure']    = TRUE;
   $config['cookie_httponly']     = FALSE;
```

What the non-working site shows in the value field:

```
a%3A5%3A%7Bs%3A10%3A%22session_id%22%3Bs%3A32%3A%22d10535309de4fe94cf3ab8f18696b541%22%3Bs%3A10%3A%22ip_address%22%3Bs%3A13%3A%22000.000.000.0004%22%3Bs%3A10%3A%22user_agent%22%3Bs%3A68%3A%22Mozilla%2F5.0+%28X11%3B+Linux+x86_64%3B+rv%3A60.0%29+Gecko%2F20100101+Firefox%2F60.0%22%3Bs%3A13%3A%22last_activity%22%3Bi%3A1561497096%3Bs%3A9%3A%22user_data%22%3Bs%3A0%3A%22%22%3B%7D51b0591e7a6e64db0d7b1690138b3d3d85aff629
```

I swapped out the IP address and domain for obvious reasons. I'm not sure why it is showing the entire array instead of just the ID, or what might be influencing the sessions to behave like this. I enabled logging, but it's not helping a whole lot. Just trying to get another set of eyes on this. Forgot to mention that I'm auto-loading the database and session libraries.

Edit: So I was looking a bit further into it, and I was trying to log into my user area that I have built on one of the websites and it was giving me some SQL errors. First it wasn't including the table name, despite it being present in the sess_save_path. I added sess_table_name with the appropriate name and that fixed that initial problem, but then it stated that there was an issue after the where clause with the session_id field. I'm not using a field name session_id, nor last_activity, nor user_data. I downloaded a fresh copy of 3.1.10 and that is indeed what it is looking for under system/libraries/Session.php, but I'm not able to find this anywhere in the manual. Even after adjusting the names in Session.php to see what happens, nothing is inserted into the ci_sessions table.

Edit 2: I also tried changing the field names in the table to match what Session.php is looking for and, despite there not being anymore SQL errors, there is still nothing being inserted into the table.

Answer (score 0):

Issue was corrected by rolling back to a previous version of CI 3 (3.1.6 I believe). I'm not sure what changed between versions with the way sessions are handled, but I'll be sure to scour the documentation to figure that out.